# Asihttprequest ,get xml,but the Xml will change very much

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, asihttprequest

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
[super viewDidLoad]; currentCount = 0; 
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dota.uuu9.com/rss.xml"]];
 [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(failMethod:)]; 
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(finishMethod:)]; 
[request setDelegate:self]; 
[request startSynchronous]; 
} 
-(void)finishMethod:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request{ 
NSLog(@"%@",request.responseString);
}
```

i should get the xml information of 2014,but sometimes i will get the 2013's

Comment: that is completely depends on the server side code. contact your server team

Comment: Also you should probably stop using ASIHTTPRequest if you can. It's old, unsupported and probably using deprecated APIs by now. I suggest AFNetworking instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to `ASIHTTPRequest` request, but on what the server returns. If you just paste your `URL` on chrome's address bar it will auto-format it for easy reading. As you can see the data returned contains both 2014 and 2013 content.

Try looking at the server's API for possible parameters that you can specify in order to filter the results. If a `GET` parameter is required, simply append it to your `URL`. If a `POST` parameter is required, you can add it like this:

```
[request setPostValue:myValue forKey:myParamName];
```